# Am I doing connection pooling correctly? Using node-postgres library

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am reading the documentation and trying to figure out connection pooling.

The documentation says that the pool should be long lived, so I have created a `config/db.js` file where I create `pool` and export it:

```
/* src/config/db.js */
const pg = require('pg');

const dbConfig = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  max: 25,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 5000
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(dbConfig);

module.exports = {
  pool
};
```

I have a bunch of routes and controllers.  For example, I have `/markers` endpoint which has a few methods in the controller.  **In the controller file, I am importing pool from the `config/db.js` and using it.  Is that OK?**

```
const pool = require('../config/db').pool;

const create = function (req, res, next) {
  const data = {
    created_by: req.body.createdBy,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    lat: req.body.lat,
    lng: req.body.lng
  };

  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) {
      done();
      // console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err });
    }
    client.query(
      'INSERT INTO markers(created_by, title, description, lat, lng, geography)\
       values($1, $2, $3, $4::decimal, $5::decimal, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5::decimal, $4::decimal), $6))',
      [
        data.created_by,
        data.title,
        data.description,
        data.lat,
        data.lng,
        4326
      ],
      function(err, res) {
        done();
        if (err) {
          // console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  });
};
```

Also, how do I check that the insert was successful so that I don't just return a 200 success if there's no error without knowing if the insert was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's correct.

as for checking error, you can see right there in the callback where you check `if (err)`, in case no err is return, that mean the insertion is success.

Comment: Thanks!  But since I can't access the `res` from the create function, how to best handle that?